# Reference request - result regarding long exact sequence of sets of homotopy classes of maps

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am looking for a reference for the following result, which I have not been able to find in the literature. I'd also welcome any comments on whether it is somehow known to be "folklore" or not.

Let $W$ denote a $CW$-complex such that $W \simeq \Sigma Y$ for a CW-complex $Y$, let and $(X,A)$ denote a $CW$-pair. There is a long exact sequence of homotopy classes of maps, of which the following is a segment

$$\dots {\longrightarrow} [\Sigma W, X] \overset{j}\longrightarrow [(CW,W),(X,A)] \overset{\partial}\longrightarrow [W,A] \longrightarrow \dots$$
where the first map is induced by the inclusion, first writing $f \colon \Sigma W \longrightarrow X$ as the map of pairs $\overline{f} \colon (CW,W) \longrightarrow (X,*)$, and the second is induced by the restriction.

Suppose that we are given a space $\widehat{\Sigma W}$ and a pair $(\widehat{CW},\widehat{W})$ such that there is a homotopy equivalence $\widehat{\Sigma W} \simeq \Sigma W$ and a homotopy equivalence of pairs $(\widehat{CW},\widehat{W}) \simeq (CW,W)$. We obtain the following segment of the isomorphic long exact sequence

$$\dots {\longrightarrow} [\widehat{\Sigma W}, X] \overset{\widehat{j}}\longrightarrow [(\widehat{CW},\widehat{W}),(X,A)] \overset{\widehat{\partial}}\longrightarrow [\widehat{W},A] \longrightarrow \dots$$

Let $n \geq 1$, and denote by $\{(F_i,Z_i) \}_{i=1}^n$ a collection of $CW$-pairs such that for all $i \in n$, $F_i \subseteq \widehat{\Sigma W}$, and there is a homotopy equivalence of pairs $(F_i,Z_i) \simeq (\widehat{CW},\widehat{W})$. Suppose also that for all $i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $i \neq j$, $(F_i \backslash Z_i) \cap (F_j \backslash Z_j) = \emptyset$.

Now, denote by $B=\left(\widehat{\Sigma W} \backslash (\bigcup_i F_i)\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_i Z_i\right)$. Suppose that we are given a map $f \colon \widehat{\Sigma W} \longrightarrow X$ such that $f|_B \subseteq A$. Then $$\widehat{j}([f]) = \sum_i \left[f|_{F_i}\right] \in [(\widehat{CW},\widehat{W}),(X,A)]$$ where I'm somewhat abusing notation by omitting the respective isomorphisms from the terms in the sum.

Comment: The sequence appears on pg.429 of Toda's article [*A Survey of Homotopy Theory*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870873901242?via%3Dihub).

Comment: Thanks Tyrone. Do you have any thoughts on whether or not the result is perhaps too trivial to be thought to require a proof by some authors?

Comment: Switzer perhaps! It discusses exact and co-exact sequences in the category of pointed spaces so that applying a homotooy functorcas you desire gives exact sequences of groups.